# State parameters are lost on refresh AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, session-storage

I am storing an object in session storage for `previousState` and `currentState` however a refresh makes previousState disappear. I'm updating both on `$transitions.onSuccess`. It looks like the `transition.from()` property gets lost.

```
$transitions.onSuccess({}, function(transition) {
    var tempTransitionFrom = transition.from();
    var tempTransitionTo = transition.to();
    appState.update('previousState', tempTransitionFrom.name);
    appState.update('currentState', tempTransitionTo.name);
});
```

This is my appState.update function

```
service.update = function(propertyName, property) {
    service.data[propertyName] = property;
    $window.sessionStorage["appState"] = JSON.stringify(service.data);
};
```

`currentState` is fine as it stays there but what should I do to keep the `previousState` from disappearing?

Comment: disappearing? aren't you overwriting it? (in `$window.sessionStorage["appState"]`)

Comment: aaaaand that is the answer... What a brain disfunction.